# Specifying bar colours in ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I've got a barplot with 30 columns. I want to give the first 19 a set colour, with the remainder being a different colour. (See chart below).  [image]

I've tried making a vector of colours. I specified the names of the columns in the chart;

`AMR_antibiotics <- c("AMIK", "GEN", "AMC", "AMP", "IMI", "P.T4", "FAZ", "FOV", "POD", "TAZ", "LEX", "CHL", "ENRO", "MAR", "ORB", "PRA", "DOX", "TET", "SXT", "AMOX", "AMPIC", "OXA", "PEN", "CEZ", "CPZ", "CEQ", "K.C", "MAF", "PIR", "ERY")`

I then tried using the following code for assigning colours;

`AMR_colours <- c(AMIK:SXT="steelblue", AMOX:ERY="coral3")`

I would then end up adding AMR_colours into my ggplot code using scale_fill_manual (values = AMR_colours)

This hasn't worked, is it because trying to do this with the above code is completely wrong? I thought it would be an easier way rather than having to go through each column manually and repeating the same colours?

If this is completely wrong, any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would make a vector of colors, and assign the names:

```
AMR_colours = c(rep("steelblue",19),rep("coral3",11))
names(AMR_colours) = AMR_antibiotics
```

To illustrate:

```
df = data.frame(x=rep(AMR_antibiotics,3),
y=runif(3*length(AMR_antibiotics)),VAR=rep(1:3,each=length(AMR_antibiotics)))

df$x = factor(df$x,levels=AMR_antibiotics)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=x))+
geom_col()+
facet_wrap(~VAR,ncol=1)+
scale_fill_manual(values=AMR_colours)
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend is a bit too long, so if you mean to summarize them as `AMIK:SXT`, and `AMOX:ERY`, you can try:

```
df$fill = ifelse(df$x %in% AMR_antibiotics[1:19],"AMIK:SXT","AMOX:ERY")
fill_two = c("AMIK:SXT"="steelblue", "AMOX:ERY"="coral3")
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=fill))+
    geom_col()+
    facet_wrap(~VAR,ncol=1)+
    scale_fill_manual(values=fill_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a new column to the dataframe identifying the appropriate colour.

```r
#List the first 19 as colour 1, and the second 11 as colour 2
AMR_antibiotics <- data.frame("Antibiotic" = c("AMIK", "GEN", "AMC", "AMP", "IMI", "P.T4", "FAZ", "FOV", "POD", "TAZ", "LEX", "CHL", "ENRO", "MAR", "ORB", "PRA", "DOX", "TET", "SXT", "AMOX", "AMPIC", "OXA", "PEN", "CEZ", "CPZ", "CEQ", "K.C", "MAF", "PIR", "ERY"),
                             "colour" = c(rep(1,19), rep(2,11)))

#Bind this new lookup table to your original data using the appropriate column name. 

NewData <- full_join(Origin_data, AMR_antibiotics , by = c( "OriginData Column Name","Antibiotic"))

#Plot using colour as an aesthetic on geom_bar
ggplot(...)+
 geom_bar(aes(...,color = colour))
```